# Is there a way to 'time travel' in Elasticsearch for integration tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch and am trying to figure out how to do some time dependent integration testing with my rails app. I have some business logic that requires results be returned only when the search is preformed on Monday through Friday and to return no results on Saturday and Sunday. I don't know how I would force Elasticsearch to 'time travel' to an appropriate day to test that logic. For my rails app I can use `Timecop` to accomplish this, but am looking for a way to do something similar with my ES cluster. Or, perhaps this is an incorrect approach...

Comment: [tomecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop)

Comment: Whats the use case? Are you doing something like a "stores open today" search?

Comment: Maybe only execute the search on days that are valid?

Comment: @max Yes, very much like that.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution for this? We are exactly looking for the same scenario. It would be really helpful if you have found out a way. We are using Mocha for integration tests